# Why does my JavaScript only return half the element text?

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer, getelementbyid

I have the following code. If you view the website I am trying to return the text "3843/10000". However, when I run my code all I get in the .txt file is "10000". Am I missing something obvious?

When I run the code multiple times the 3843/ eventually populates the .txt file. Why doesn't it do this first time round?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function start() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  const fs = require('fs/promises')
  await page.goto('https://mint.silks.io/nft/silks-io-2023-02-04-be7b')

  const names = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(" #root > div > main > section.sc-hHLeRK.euoVKl > div.sc-hAZoDl.iNrOsm > div > div.sc-dmRaPn.gLjUVc.event-info-container__right > div:nth-child(1) > div > h4")).map(x => x.textContent)
  })

  await fs.writeFile("names.txt", names.join("\r\n"))
  await browser.close()
}

start()
```

Comment: Probably because that element only gets populated after the page loads. And if the `10000` is a "known" static value, and only the `3843` part gets fetched in a background request, then there might well be a certain moment where the element content _is_ only `10000`.

Comment: That makes sense, is there a way around this, perhaps a delay?

Comment: You could warp the return statement inside your `page.evaluate` into a timeout, and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you try `page.waitForSelector`? [Don't use a timeout or browser-generated selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/).